# How to check if sum of some contiguous subarray is equal to N?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So say I have a list sequences such as this.

I want to remove all sequences where its total sum = N and/or it has a contiguous subarray with sum = N.

For example, if N = 4, then (1,1,2) is not valid since its total is 4. (1,1,3) is also not valid since the (1,3) is also 4. (1,3,1) is also not valid for the same reason.

```
lst = [ 
    (1,1,1), (1,1,2), (1,1,3), 
    (1,2,1), (1,2,2), (1,2,3), 
    (1,3,1), (1,3,2), (1,3,3), 
    (2,1,1), (2,1,2), (2,1,3), 
    (2,2,1), (2,2,2), (2,2,3), 
    (2,3,1), (2,3,2), (2,3,3), 
    (3,1,1), (3,1,2), (3,1,3), 
    (3,2,1), (3,2,2), (3,2,3), 
    (3,3,1), (3,3,2), (3,3,3) 
]
```

What are some ways to do this?

I'm currently trying to see if I'm able to remove sequences whose total is not necessarily a multiple of N but not its contiguous subarrays, but I'm unsuccessful

```
   for elements in list(product(range(1,n), repeat=n-1)):
        lst.append(elements)
    for val in lst:
        if np.cumsum(val).any() %n != 0:
            lst2.append(val) # append value to a filtered list
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the numbers in your little sequences like (1,1,3) are nonnegative? Also, what is the maximum length of these "little" sequences?

Comment: Yes, they are guaranteed to be negative and the maximum length is N-1.

Comment: You mean they are guaranteed to be nonnegative? If so, there is a very efficient linear time solution given by Neb. @Thegreatfoo So, I think it is also worth mentioning in the question how big N can be and what are the negativity conditions on the elements.

Comment: *Non-negative, my mistake. Also the range of N in this case is 2 <= n <= 1000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.combinations` to generate all combinations of slice indices to test for sums of subsequences:

```
from itertools import combinations
[t for t in lst if not any(sum(t[l:h+1]) == 4 for l, h in combinations(range(len(t)), 2))]
```

This returns:

```
[(1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 2), (2, 3, 3), (3, 2, 1), (3, 2, 3), (3, 3, 2), (3, 3, 3)]
```

Comment: If max length is `N-1`, the OP may need it to generalize to any `N`

Answer (score 2):

You can split your problem into two subproblems:

1. The elements in your list sum up to N. Then you can simply test:

   ```
   if sum(myList) == N:
       # do fancy stuff
   ```
2. The elements in your list do **not** sum up to N. In this case, there might be a subsequence that sum up to N. To find it, let's define two pointers, `l` and `r`. Their name stand for `left` and `right` and will define the boundaries of your subsequence. Then, the solution is the following:

   ```
   r = 1
   l = 0
   while r <= len(myList):
       sum_ = sum(myList[l:r])
       if sum_ < 4:
           r += 1
       elif sum_ > 4:
           l += 1
       else:
           # do fancy stuff and exit from the loop
           break
   ```

   It works as follows. First you initialize `l` and `r` so that you consider the subsequence consisting of only the first element of `myList`. Then, you sum the element of the subsequence and if the sum is lower than N, you enlarge the subsequence by adding `1` to `r`. If it is greater than N, then you restrict the subsequence by adding `1` to `l`.

---

**Note thanks to eozd**:

The above algorithm works only if the elemnent of the list are non-negative.

Comment: The second algorithm works only if the elements in the sequence are nonnegative. I think it is worth mentioning.

Comment: You are right, I assumed they were all non-negative because of the example given by the OP